# How to design for Android Multiple Screens?

Tags: android, android-layout

1st Image: Default Normal Screen
  2nd Image: Galaxy Nexus 4.65" (Eventhough it looks larger, it is under normal screen)
  3rd Image: Large Screen

how to design for particular screen size? I mean both 1st and 2nd image comes under 'normal screen'. Suppose If I create new layout folder for Galaxy Nexus (4.65",720x1280) and i was working on it, it affects default layout folder.

[image: Normal Screen Nexus One]

[image: Normal Screen Galaxy Nexus]

[image: Large Screen]

Answer (score 2):

if above solution does not work.try this ,it will surely work ,i have tested this. if you want your app work on different different version of OS.
Use these three layout's.

```
                            For 
                            tablet>3.2 and up verion
                            1-layout-sw600dp


                            For 
                            tablet<3.2 and lower version
                            1-layout-xlarge


                            For 
                            Smart phone
                            1-layout
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my general guide on how to design for different screens:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12739568/1369222

If you are looking to target only the samsung galaxy nexus, see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212675/1369222

Answer (score 0):

use this link http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

here they  provide drawable (if you want to use image) for each screen with the same image ,your device automatically choose their own pic according to their density.

```
res/
    drawable-xhdpi/
        awesomeimage.png
    drawable-hdpi/
        awesomeimage.png
    drawable-mdpi/
        awesomeimage.png
    drawable-ldpi/
        awesomeimage.png
```

and this is for layout ,make new folder in your res folder and give name it layout-large and put same xml file in this i.e main.xml.

```
res/
        layout/
            main.xml
        layout-large/
            main.xml
```

Comment: please don't post another answer. Instead, edit the same answer and whatever you need to say.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go if your looking for something like this, idk, im trying to get some votes im kicked off questions and im stuck, gota get back on this thing

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
Generalised Dpi values for screens:

ldpi Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi)
mdpi Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
hdpi Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
Therefore generalised size of your resources (assuming they are full screen):

ldpi
Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
mdpi
Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
hdpi
Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
xhdpi
Vertical = 960 * 320 / 160 = 1920px
Horizontal = 720 * 320 / 160 = 1440px

px = dp*dpi/160
```